# Controlling the number of threads when using c#5 async / await

Tags: multithreading, async-await, c#-5.0

I am looking into using the new async/await keyworks in c#5 and reading [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx)

I see the following example

```
async void ArchiveDocuments(List<Url> urls)
{
  Task archive = null;
  for(int i = 0; i < urls.Count; ++i)
  {
    var document = await FetchAsync(urls[i]);
    if (archive != null)
      await archive;
    archive = ArchiveAsync(document);
  }
}
```

Presumably if the Urls list is VERY long we might get into a situation where the thread cound gets out of control.

What I'd like to know is what the recommended way to control the number of threads used. Is there a way to specify a threadpool or a max number?

With the TPL you can use the options to control the max number of threads
ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism. Perhaps some way of combining await and Task might be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of that example is to show a "pipeline" pattern where there is at most one Fetch and one Archive executing concurrently.

`async` does not mean concurrent, it means non-blocking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was just using that snippit as an example of something that uses await in a loop. I'm trying to get to the bottom of how many threads it would use. If the await is in a loop like this then is the loop only continued after the await returns.

From that article :
“if the task we are awaiting has not yet completed then sign up the rest of this method as the continuation of that task, and then return to your caller immediately; the task will invoke the continuation when it completes.”

This seems to suggest that only one thread would be used for the FetchAsync

Comment: When you execute an `await` expression, the rest of the `async` method, including any state like loop indices, is stored in a state machine object. The `async` method then returns control to its caller - it exits. So no, the loop does not continue executing. When the awaited method completes, control returns to the state machine, which then continues execution.

Comment: There is *some* concurrency here, if you look at it another way. When the `async` method returns to its caller due to an `await`, the `async` method itself does not continue running, but the `Fetch` and/or `Archive` operations *do*. I view `async`/`await` as a way of managing concurrency in a programmer-friendly way.

Comment: @chrisp_68: `Task`s do not necessarily use threads. `Fetch` is probably I/O bound, so it would not use a thread at all. If `Archive` is I/O bound as well, and if `ArchiveDocuments` is called from a UI thread, then there would be no threadpool usage at all (except for very short operations such as completing asynchronous I/O). `TaskCompletionSource` is the class for creating `Task`s without threads.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` and `await` keywords do not create any threads themselves. That's totally up to the method that handles the task itself.

In fact, operations like file-system I/O or network connections, usually don't need any threads to run asynchronously. The hardware does what the hardware does and when it's done the related event is fired (back in C#).

If you want to control the number of threads, you need to change the method that creates threads - and it has nothing to do with `async` and `awaits`.